# Argument of a general Complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

How to prove that for large $k>N$, $\frac{1}{2} \le a \le 3\pi$, $0 <b \le 3\pi$, the argument of $z$ satisfy
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{2} \le \mathrm{arg}z<\frac{3\pi}{4},
\end{align*}
where $$z=\frac{i(k-2 \pi b)+2\pi a}{2 \sqrt{a-i b}}$$
I tried to split $z=x+i y$ and try to prove that $y>-x$. The inequality turns to be much complicated.

Comment: For large $k,$ the argument of the numerator goes to $\pi/2$ so you just have to worry about the argument of the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt {a+ib} =c+id$ with $c,d$ real. The the real part of $z$ is $2\pi ac-d (k-2 \pi b)/|\sqrt {a-ib}|^{2}$ which is clearly negative for large values of $k$. Now  note that the argument of a complex number lies between $\frac {\pi} 2$ and $\frac {3\pi} 4$ iff its real part is negative.